# Problema ao baixar um arquivo com nome acentuado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu tenho uma função que retorna um arquivo para download, quando o nome do arquivo possui caracteres acentuados e um certo tamanho, o arquivo baixado vem com o nome errado (no Chrome vem o nome da minha função e no Firefox vem o nome baralhado),

```
public FileStreamResult _ObtemArquivo(long idArquivo)
{
    DtoArquivo arquivo = null;
    //  ---------------------
    //  ... Obtém o "arquivo"
    //  ---------------------

    FileStreamResult retorno = null;
    if (arquivo != null)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(arquivo.Bytes);

        //  Usando o nome do arquivo diretamente o erro ocorre em todos os Browsers.
        retorno = File(stream, "binary", arquivo.Nome);

        //retorno = File(stream, "binary", Uri.EscapeUriString(arquivo.Nome));
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

Usando **"Uri.EscapeUriString"** o erro não ocorre no Chrome mas no Firefox todos os arquivos com acentuação no nome vem errado (mostrando a formatação no nome, **Ex:** %C3%A1%C3%A1%20%20C3%A2C3%A2_abcdefghijlmnpqrstuvxzkwy_abcdefghijlmnopqrstuv).

Também testei com `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` e `Uri.EscapeDataString` e ambos não funcionaram da forma desejada em todos os browsers.

Quando o nome do arquivo possui acentuação mas é um nome curto, por exemplo,

> áá ââ_abcdefghijlmnpqrstuvxzkwy.abc

não há problema, o **Content-Disposition** gerado no Response header é

> **Conten-Disposition**: attachment; filename="=?utf-8?B?w6HDoSAgw6LDol9hYmNkZWZnaGlqbG1ucHFyc3R1dnh6a3d5LmZwcg==?="

apenas quando o nome é maior, como por exemplo,

> áá ââ_abcdefghijlmnpqrstuvxzkwy_abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxzkwy.abc

o erro é gerado e o **Conten-Disposition** gerado é

> **Conten-Disposition**: attachment; filename="=?utf-8?B?w6HDoSAgw6LDol9hYmNkZWZnaGlqbG1ucHFyc3R1dnh6a3d5X2FiY2Rl?=%0d%0a =?utf-8?B?ZmdoaWpsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnh6a3d5LmZwcg==?="

eu acredito que o problema é causado porque no segundo **Conten-Disposition** possui dois `?utf-8?`, mas ainda não entendi o porque isso acontence e como resolver esse problema.

Qualquer ajuda para entender ou contornar esse problema será muito bem vinda, Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Sou novo no assunto, mais já tentou utilizar o
Namespace: System.Globalization.

E no arquivo para download CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
E por que tive um problema semelhante e com esse namespce resolveu.